# How to page-up / page-down through vim terminal

Tags: linux, vim, neovim

I am new user to Vim and I want to use vim's embedded terminal (called by `:term`). Unfortunately, I cannot use this terminal as I want to. The `Shift` + `PageUp` / `Shift` + `PageDown` duo (to move up and down through logs) does not work. I tried to solve the issue, with found mapping `tnoremap <CTRL-V><CTRL-PAGEUP> : tabp<CR>`, but this one does not work.

Comment: Exit insert mode then use the usual Vim commands (e.g. Ctrl-B for page up). `:help scrolling`

Comment: While I am in `TERMINAL` mode (when I switch from pane of text in `NORMAL` mode to vim terminal) Ctrl-B does not work.

Comment: I meant, exit terminal job mode (Ctrl-W N) into terminal normal mode. In terminal job mode, cursor and scrolling is controlled by the job, and you cannot scroll.`:help Terminal-Job`: "When the job is running the contents of the terminal is under control of the job. That includes the cursor position." `:help Terminal-Normal`: "When the job outputs lines in the terminal, such that the contents scrolls off the top, those lines are remembered and can be seen in Terminal-Normal mode."

Comment: Is `shift`+`PageUp` the scroll binding of your terminal? What are you exactly looking at in the terminal? logs? Wouldn't it be better to open them in vim?

Answer (score 3):

The best way that I've found to do this is to start a tmux session within the Vim terminal, then scroll in tmux copy mode. I can't necessarily give any key-bindings for this because it really depends on your tmux setup. You can make tmux use the Vim-like `<C-u>` and `<C-d>` (up and down half a page) by adding the following to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -gw mode-keys vi
```

For that matter, why not use vi mode in bash?

```
set -o vi
```

To actually scroll in tmux then, you need to use your tmux prefix key (defaults to `<C-b>`) followed by `[` to put it in "copy mode".

---

Here is an example of my Vim/Tmux terminal. Note that at the end I turn off the status bar by typing `<C-b>` (the default tmux prefix hotkey) followed by `:` (put tmux in command mode). Finally enter the command `set -g status off`.

[image]

---

However, I normally only do this if I am using GVim or MacVim, but for the most part I run Vim inside of a tmux session in a terminal which lets me get all of this for free.